# How to output string with line breaks, and separate before the number? [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, string

Not sure if I clearly describe my question, my original string is:

"1.you are beautiful 2.hello world 3.Thanks!"

I want the output to be:

"1.you are beautiful"

"2.hello world"

"3.Thanks!"

or

"1.you are beautiful

2.hello world

3.Thanks!"

I used split() when the sentence contains comma or period. However, I am thinking if I can write a function by using the number. For example, if type(item)==int then add a line break

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. This will only work for single digit numbers and will work with or without the period.

```
a='1.you are beautiful 2.hello world 3.Thanks!'
out=''
for ch in a:
    if ch.isdigit():
        out+='\n'+ch
    else:
        out+=ch
print(out)
```

If you want to detect any length number (e.g. 11) you would have to use enumerate(a) and "look ahead" to find the period '.' with another for loop and then add the new line or look into use the re package and Regular Expressions.

Comment: @Lydialime If that works for you please accept the answer